# ReactJs close input textfield on value change

Tags: reactjs, textfield

I have the following problem: I have an input textfield and scanning a barcode. But the textfield will not close automatically. If I enter the numbers by keyboard it will close automatically. Did I something wrong? Is the scanner to fast? Any idea?

```
const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    
const onValueChange = (event) => {
        if(event.target.value.length===16){
          setOpen(false);
        }
    };

<TextField autoFocus onChange={onValueChange} margin="dense" id="number"  type="text" inputProps={{minlength: 16,maxlength:16}} fullWidth variant="outlined" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
<TextField autoFocus 
onChange={onValueChange} 
margin="dense" 
id="number"  
type="text" 
inputProps={{minlength: 16,maxlength:16}} 
fullWidth 
variant="outlined"
onBlur={() => setOpen(false)} /* NEW */
 />
```